# Import storybook component to another angular project

Tags: angular, components, storybook

I have to do a Demo in which i have two types of projects. The first project will be a bucket of components and the nexts projects consume the components of the first projects.

I want do the first proyect with Storybook and if i do "npm run storybook" works perfectly. If i do "npm run build-storybook", it generate static files correctly.

But the question is, how can i use this components in my another project? I dont find the correct documentantation and i'm very confused.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make a storybook library to share with other projects.

Here a tutorial (it seems the official API is not available at the moment):
[how-to-build-and-publish-angular-library](https://medium.com/@jinalshah999/how-to-build-and-publish-angular-library-a333d6ff12c0)